# CAS Single Logout Issue

Tags: java, cas, jasig

I have a Jasig CAS 3.5.2.1 version and two separate applications (let's say app-A and app-B) authenticating their users over CAS server (using pac4j-play-cas-client).

Assume that a user signs in to app-A and then signs in to app-B using different service tickets. When the user signs out from app-A, I expect CAS server to send logout callback to both app-A and app-B logout callback services. But it seems CAS server only sends logout callback to app-A.

Single Singout configuration on my CAS server is as follows:

```
> <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
>        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
>        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
>        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">
>         <description>
>                 Argument Extractors are what are used to translate HTTP requests into requests of the appropriate protocol (i.e. CAS,
> SAML, SAML2,
>                 OpenId, etc.).  By default CAS and SAML are enabled.
>         </description>
>         <bean
>                 id="casArgumentExtractor"
>                 class="org.jasig.cas.web.support.CasArgumentExtractor"
>          p:httpClient-ref="noRedirectHttpClient"
>          p:disableSingleSignOut="${slo.callbacks.disabled:false}" />
> 
>         <bean id="samlArgumentExtractor" class="org.jasig.cas.web.support.SamlArgumentExtractor"
>              p:httpClient-ref="noRedirectHttpClient"
>              p:disableSingleSignOut="${slo.callbacks.disabled:false}" />
> 
>         <util:list id="argumentExtractors">
>                 <ref bean="casArgumentExtractor" />
>                 <ref bean="samlArgumentExtractor" />
>         </util:list> </beans>
```

Am I missing a point, why couldn't I get a logout callback for app-B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the Chairman of CAS and founder of CAS in the cloud (https://www.casinthecloud.com). I'm the creator of the pac4j library as well.

The CAS logout is handled by this controller: https://github.com/Jasig/cas/blob/3.5.2.1/cas-server-core/src/main/java/org/jasig/cas/web/LogoutController.java and logout requests are really sent by this code: https://github.com/Jasig/cas/blob/3.5.2.1/cas-server-core/src/main/java/org/jasig/cas/ticket/TicketGrantingTicketImpl.java#L142. Nothing relevant in your logs?

Comment: Thanks a lot Jerome. After inspecting the classes you've shared I realized that I must use the same TGT for all client applications so that the SLO mechanism can operate as expected.